# Phalcon PHP validation Uniqueness but allow empty values

Tags: php, validation, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I have the following validation:

```php
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness;

class Users extends BaseModel {
    public function validation() {
        $validator = new Validation();
        $validator->add('some_data', new Uniqueness([
                    'message' => 'this field must be unique or epmty'
        ]));
        // some other rules (...)
        return $this->validate($validator);
    }
}
```

The question is how to allow pass empty data.
I'd like to save in database NULL if data is empty or unique value if it's passed.

Comment: Now the ORM allows me to store only 1 epmty value, because each next one is not unique

Comment: It may help to know that you are able to turn off the default null validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to do the following in your model class:

```
public function validation()
    {
        $validator = new Validation();
        $validator->add(
            'example',
            new Uniqueness(
                [
                    'message' => 'Example must be unique',
                    'allowEmpty' => true,
                ]
            )
        );
        return $this->validate($validator);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```php
public function validation()
{
    $validator = new Validation();

    if (!empty($this->getSomeData())) {
        $validator->add('some_data', new Uniqueness([
            'message' => 'this field must be unique or epmty'
        ]));
    }
    // some other rules (...)
    return $this->validate($validator);
}
```

Comment: Thx, your solution is more simple, but conditional should be: if (!empty($this->getSomeDatal())) ;)

Comment: you are right but the code is all hypothetical thats why i didn't double check and i just copied your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution with CallbackValidator

```php
    $validator->add('some_data', new CallbackValidator([
                    "callback" => function($data) {
                        if (!empty($data->getSomeData())) {
                            return new Uniqueness([
                                "message" => "this field must be unique or epmty"
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
        ]));
```